# Problema con JQuery y variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Hace unos días empece a trabajar con JS y JQuery pero tengo una duda que no entiendo cuando intento enviar unas variables por Api Rest.

JS

```
$('body').on('click', '#signupButton', function () {
    $("#signupButton").val("Procesando....");
    var statusEmail = $('#remail').attr('rel');
    var statusUsername = $('#rusername').attr('rel');
    var statusGender = $('#rgender').attr('rel');
    var statusSearch = $('#rsearch').attr('rel');
    if (statusEmail > 0 && statusUsername > 0 && statusGender > 0 && statusSearch > 0) {
        username = $('#rusername').val();
        password = $('#rpassword').val();
        gender = $('#rgender').val();
        search = $('#rsearch').val();
        email = $('#remail').val();
        encodedata = JSON.stringify({ "username": username, "password": password, "email": email, "gender": gender, "search": search });

        var url = $.apiBaseUrl + 'api/signup';
        ajaxPost(url, encodedata, function (data) {
            if (data.signup.length) {
                if (parseInt(data.signup[0].status)) {
                    var url = $.baseUrl + 'welcome.php';
                    window.location.replace(url);
                }
                else {
                    $("#signupButton").val("Sign Up");
                }

            }
            else {
                $("#signupError").show().html("El usuario o email ya existen.");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#signupError").show().html("Ingrese información válida!");
    }

    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" name="signup" id="signup" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" >
        <div id="row">
            <input class="form-control reg" id="remail" type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Tu correo electrónico" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false"  rel="0">
        </div>
        <div id="row">
            <input class="form-control reg" id="rusername" type="text" name="username" maxlength="25"  autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" rel='0' placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">

            <div id="urlText"><span id="baseURL" class="labelURL" ></span><span id="usernameLabel"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="row">
            <select class="reg" id="rgender" name="gender" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false"  rel='0'>
                <option selected>Seleccione su genero</option>
                <option value="1">Masculino</option>
                <option value="2">Femenino</option>
                <option value="3">Sin genero</option>
            </select>
        </div>

       <div id="row">
            <select class="reg" id="rsearch" name="search" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false"  rel='0'>
                <option selected>¿Qué estas buscando?</option>
                <option value="1">Trabajo Eventual</option>
                <option value="2">Trabajo tiempo completo</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <input class="form-control reg" id="rpassword" type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Crear una contraseña" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" >
            <div id="terms"><span class="agreeMessage">Con su registro, ud esta aceptando nuestros </span> <a href="terms.php" class="terms" target="_blank">terminos y condiciones.</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="has-error  displaynone" id="signupError"></div>
        <div style="clear:both" class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" class="wallbutton buttonSignUp" value="Registrarse" id="signupButton">  
        </div>
    </form>
```

No entiendo porque siempre me dice información invalida.

Comment: No necesitas hacer esto para enviarlo por Ajax: `encodedata=JSON.stringify({"username": username,"password": password,"email": email,"gender": gender, "search": search});` Bastaría esto: **`encodedata={"username": username,"password": password,"email": email,"gender": gender, "search": search};`**

Comment: Si, lo probe de esa manera pero tampoco funciona. Sinceramente nose porque no me toma las variables

Comment: Hola puedas dar mas datos, por favor, en dónde te dice información invalidad, en la consola, en tu Api, en tu formulario?

Comment: en el if .... {
$("#signupError").show().html("Ingrese información válida!");     
}

Comment: el problema son los dos <select>. Nose porque no me toma los datos de cada uno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que veo es que todos los campos de entrada tienen un atributo `rel` que vale `"0"`. Dicho atributo sólo es "estándar" cuando se usa en un enlace a un recurso (tags `<a>`,`<link>` o `<area>`), en el resto de elementos no tiene sentido y tu código no parece modificarlo (así que no sé qué uso le das), con lo que la condición previa a validar los inputs y selects de tu código no se cumple nunca (espera que TODOS los atributos `rel` tengan un valor mayor a 0).

Comment: En realidad, la idea es que todos los valores sean mayores a  0 para que cumpla la condición. Mi problema son los <SELECTS> porque con los input  funciona perfecto la condición, pero cuando defino los statusGender y statusSearch > 0 no me toma los datos. Por eso, sinceramente no entiendo.

Comment: En qué momento cambian tus valores rel a otro número que no sea 0?

Comment: cuando el APIREST recibe la información en {$data = json_decode($request->getBody());} en PHP. hago un if comparando los valores >0 antes de guardarlos en la BD